# How to export Txt/Text file to new folder?

Tags: powershell

This code does taking newest text file from the folder.

```
$dir = "C:\logsnew\Application"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1  
$latest.name
```

showing like this

```
C:\Users\kimi> $dir = "C:\logsnew\Application"
C:\Users\kimi> $latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1  
C:\Users\kimi> $latest.name
4552-4084-63585921993.txt
```

I would like to put this newest txt file "4552-4084-63585921993.txt" to new folder name "logstop1".

So I try like this:

```
$dir = "C:\logsnew\Application"
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir |
  Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending |
  Select-Object -First 1 |
  Add-Content C:\logsTop1
```

but this error happens:

> Add-Content : Access to the path 'C:\logsTop1' is denied.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Add-Content adds to an existing file.  You are looking to move-item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Move-Item` instead of `Add-Content` if you want to move the file or `Copy-Item` if you want to copy it.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\logsnew\Application" | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | Move-Item -Destination "C:\logspath1"
```